# GroupBy and where condition NOT IN not working simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

Hello I am trying to fetch the results from the database based on the distance and also don't want to include those rows where certain ids exist in my return data. But the problem is if I do group by then it ignores the `WHERE` condition.

Here is my query

```
SELECT ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(31.45583995) ) * COS( RADIANS( Room.lat ) )
                    * COS( RADIANS(Room.long) - RADIANS(73.12997248)) + SIN(RADIANS(31.45583995))
                    * SIN( RADIANS(Room.lat)))) AS distance, 
       `Room`.*, `User`.*, `Room`.`id` 
FROM `bring_messenger`.`room` AS `Room` 
LEFT JOIN `bring_messenger`.`user` AS `User` ON (`Room`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
JOIN `bring_messenger`.`room_member` AS `RoomMember` ON (`RoomMember`.`room_id` = `Room`.`id`)   
WHERE ((`Room`.`user_id` NOT IN (2)) OR (`RoomMember`.`member_id` NOT IN (2)))  
GROUP BY distance 
HAVING distance < 100  
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

The problem is it gives me the data which includes the `user_id = 2`. But If I remove `GROUP BY` condition then condition works successfully.

So Please help how can I not include certain rows and also sort the results based on the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Group by is used alongside **Aggregate Funcions** such as SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN, and COUNT .
And you will need to include complete group of columns mentioned in Select statement except the one (usually column resultant of aggregate function). Same distance value could exist for different combination of Room & Users, which would confuse SQL on which one of the Room's & User's data to fetch against one specific value of Distance.
Group By example:

```
SELECT 
c1, c2,..., cn, aggregate_function(ci)
FROM
table
WHERE
where_conditions
GROUP BY c1 , c2,...,cn;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you please edit my query and post as a solution if you can.. Thank you